# Unable to Prefill Values for Project and Activities in React Edit Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm working on a React application where I have an edit modal for timesheet entries. In this modal, I want to prefill the values for the "Project" and "Activity" select inputs based on the data associated with the timesheet entry I'm editing.

I've set up the state for editedTask, and I'm using it to bind the values in the input fields in the modal. However, I'm having trouble prefilling the values for the "Project" and "Activity" select inputs.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Container, Table, Button, Modal, Form,Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  editTaskByTimesheetId,
  fetchAllActivities,
  fetchAllProjects,
  getUserDataForWeek,
} from "../../services/API";

const [editedTask, setEditedTask] = useState({
    timeSheetId: null,
    task: "",
    hours: 0,
    createdDate: "",
    projectId: 0,
    userId: 0,
    activityId: 0,
  });

const handleSaveEdit = () => {
    if (editedTask.timeSheetId) {
      editTaskByTimesheetId(editedTask.timeSheetId, editedTask)
        .then((editedTimesheet) => {
          setTasksData((prevData) =>
            prevData.map((taskData) =>
              taskData.timeSheetId === editedTimesheet.timeSheetId ? editedTimesheet : taskData
            )
          );
          setShowEditModal(false);
          getUserData();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error editing timesheet entry:", error);
        });
    }
  };

<Modal show={showEditModal} onHide={() => setShowEditModal(false)}>
  <Modal.Header closeButton>
    <Modal.Title>Edit Timesheet Entry</Modal.Title>
  </Modal.Header>
  <Modal.Body>
    <Form>
      <Form.Group controlId="formTask">
        <Form.Label>Task</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="text"
          name="task"
          value={editedTask.task}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="formHours">
        <Form.Label>Hours</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="number"
          name="hours"
          value={editedTask.hours}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="formProject">
        <Form.Label>Project</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          as="select"
          name="projectId"
          value={editedTask.projectId}
          onChange={(e) => {
            handleProjectChange(e.target.value);
            handleInputChange(e);
          }}
        >
          <option value="">Select a Project</option>
          {projectNames.map((project) => (
            <option key={project.projectId} value={project.projectId}>
              {project.projectName}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group controlId="formActivity">
        <Form.Label>Activity</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          as="select"
          name="activityId"
          value={editedTask.activityId}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        >
          <option value="">Select an Activity</option>
          {relatedActivities.map((activity) => (
            <option key={activity.activityId} value={activity.activityId}>
              {activity.activityName}
            </option>
          ))}
        </Form.Control>
      </Form.Group>
    </Form>
  </Modal.Body>
  <Modal.Footer>
    <Button variant="secondary" onClick={() => setShowEditModal(false)}>
      Close
    </Button>
    <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleSaveEdit}>
      Save Changes
    </Button>
  </Modal.Footer>
</Modal>
```

My question is, how can I prefill the "Project" and "Activity" select inputs with the correct values when I open the edit modal? The editedTask state seems to work for text input fields, but I'm not sure how to handle the select inputs.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!